# MemoryCache item remove callback and exiting gracefully

Tags: c#, memorycache

After storing items in a MemoryCache, I need to do some cleanup when they get removed. I have set a removed item callback and that works great. My question is, if the app exits abnormally such as from an exception or is terminated during system shutdown, how can I ensure that my callback gets called for each object in the cache?

Additional info: the cached elements contain a running count of calls to an API - one object for each user. I want to commit those counts back to the database when they exit the cache so I don't need to run an update in the database on every call which is the current bottleneck in my process.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will. If a process crashes or exits abnormally (for example, you kill it from Task Manager) it will drop everything. This also means that your MemoryCache object will not matter any longer because it will be dropped as well.

Comment: You should probably update your question on what kind of cleanup you need. Maybe there is a different way?